# ajax response needed to be assigned to a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am implementing an image gallery using an Ajax call.

The call passes a value and gets an HTML code as a response. I checked this response and it is correct.

And if I put this code into a static DIV, the gallery works with no problems.

But if I inject the code with AJAX, when I click on an image, it opens in the window as a normal image: the gallery pop-up is not working.

What could be the cause of this problem?

The code is as follows

```js
$.ajax({

    type: 'GET',
    url: 'www.test.com',
    data: {
        type: product,
        use: 'gallery'
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#dv_gallery").append(data);
    }

});
```

the following  is the HTML code in the page

```html
 <div class="portfolio-adaptive adaptive-three" id="dv_gallery"></div>
```

Comment: data: {type:product,use:'gallery'}, ... is product a variable name or should it be a string ... i.e. data: {type:'product',use:'gallery'},

Comment: product is a variable which contains a string

Comment: You are using which server side language?

Comment: Your gallery div is inside partial?

Comment: Add the code of opening `image` in popup

Comment: Your problem is the url.  You can only use relative paths, example url: 'ajax.php', Both the webpage and the ajax "page" must be on the same server.

Comment: I am using the server side language - php

Comment: my friends, i am getting the response as needed. But when i am inserting the code inside a div, the image thumbnails are displayed correctly. The problem is when am trying to click on the image :)

Comment: Can you supply the gallery software name, or if it is yours, how do you bind events to the gallery? Also a snippet of the HTML response would be useful.

Comment: $('.swipebox').click(function(){
  $('.gallery-fix').fadeIn(0);
 });
    
 $(".swipebox").swipebox({
  useCSS : true, // false will force the use of jQuery for animations
  hideBarsDelay : 3000 // 0 to always show caption and action bar
 });
 
 $(".wide-gallery-item").swipebox({
  useCSS : true, // false will force the use of jQuery for animations
  hideBarsDelay : 3000 // 0 to always show caption and action bar
 });

Answer (score 6):

Unless the gallery (which you do not specify) is completely CSS based, you almost certainly need to call some sort of initialization code.

Usually this is taken care of by the gallery code when it loads:

```
// This "animates" all gallery DIVs **THAT EXIST NOW**
<script src="gallery.js"></script>
```

Check the gallery APIs. Say there is a call `$.gallery()` to gallerize a selector. Then you change your code to read

```
success: function(data) {

    $("#dv_gallery").append(data);

    // The $('#dv_gallery') below includes also the newly appended data
    $("#dv_gallery")
        .not(".already-initialized")
        .addClass("already-initialized")
        .gallery();
}
```

## Example with a custom gallery based on .click()

In this case you just need to intercept the click on the (say) A tags through delegation. In this hypothesis you are now doing something like

```
$('#dv_gallery a').on('click', function(event) {
   ...
});
```

and this works for those A's that exist statically. To make it work with dynamically added A tags, you should do

```
$('#dv_gallery').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
   ...
});
```

Notice that now you bind the click event to #dv_gallery, *which exists*, and tell it to act as a delegate for newly added 'a' tags by supplying an extra parameter to .on().

## Example with FancyBox:

```
// Select gallery container
$("#dv_gallery")
    // Images are embedded in A tags in Fancybox
    .find('a')
    // But we do not want to fancybox already gallerified images
    .not(".already-initialized")
    // And we want to mark as gallerified those we process now
    .addClass("already-initialized")
    // Everything is ready -- build these new A's into fancyboxes
    .fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false
    });
```

If the API is intelligent enough not to re-gallerify an already-enriched element, then you don't need to add semaphore classes but can simply do

```
$("#dv_gallery").append(data);
$("#dv_gallery").gallery();
```

Or if it is not, but you know that it adds a given class, you can directly use that one as a semaphore:

```
    $("#dv_gallery")
        .not(".gallery-class")
        .gallery();
```

## Diagnosing not-so-apparent problems with returned HTML

jQuery ought to correctly append HTML; if it does not, check the Content-Type of the returned document, and try with

```
   $("#dv_gallery").append($(data));
```

or try replacing **all** the contents of the gallery:

```
   $("#dv_gallery").html(data);
```

In both cases you will need to reinvoke any required gallery initialization code. These last two options are only diagnostic, however - if they work, it tells you that something's fishy in the returned object.

Answer (score 2):

Have u tried using the html() function of jquery?

```
$("#dv_gallery").html(data);
```

Comment: And what is problem with `append`?

Comment: `html` will replace all the previous content, `append` will add it

Comment: yes, i have tried this. But still have the same problem. Even i have tried document.getElementById("dv_gallery").innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

`$("#dv_gallery").html(data);`
Above code is working for you

Comment: if you will get data in data after ajax response then you will put your html in using html function with the use of div id using jquery

Comment: i have used this before and it is not working for me. I am getting the images displayed there. But the gallery function is not working there.

Comment: send me your code with html i will  give you solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that most likely, although your code doesn't show the `click` code, it's not being recognized because it's loaded after the fact. Nothing to do with the gallery code.

Put simply, try changing your click code from e.g.

```
$('.myClass').on( 'click', function(){ ... } )
```

To

```
$('body').on( 'click', '.myClass',  function(){ ... } )
```

This will route the click through the body and should then fire your gallery code.